# Retrieving and passing annotation data through modal segue in Storyboard

Tags: ios, ios6, mkannotation, uistoryboardsegue

I have a program that creates map annotations with a UI Detail Disclosure button that makes a modal segue to a detailed view of the annotation.  The application has been created using storyboards.

Here is the Code for the defining the annotations:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    MKPinAnnotationView *pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"PIN"];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        pin.animatesDrop = YES;
        return nil;
    }

    else {
        [pin setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorPurple];
    }

    pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button;
    pin.animatesDrop = YES;
    pin.canShowCallout = YES;

    return pin;
}
```

Here is the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{

    NewClass *annView = view.annotation;

    AnnotationView *detailView = [[AnnotationView alloc]init];

    detailView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    detailView.buildingName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my dictionary is %@", annView.title];

    detailView.desciptionText = annView.title;

    [self presentViewController:detailView animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Finally, here is the `prepareForSegue` method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowMoreInfo"]){

        AnnotationView *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        //destViewController.buildingName = ; set to name of building of selected annotation

        //destViewController.desciptionText = ; set to description of building of selected annotation (from an array or from passed data)

        destViewController.picName = ;

    }
}
```

How do I take the information from the `callOutAccessoryControlTapped` method and set the values in `prepareForSegue` method to those values?

When I use breakpoints to track data values, `annView.title` holds a string value, but it is never assigned to the value in the detail view controller for the annotation detail view.

Any information on how to pass data from a selected annotation to the prepare for segue method would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Get the title of the annotation using

```
let someTitle = sender!.title!!
```

then use someTitle to search/filter your data for the the pic, building name (or whatever else you're looking for).